# How can I correct the following SQL script?

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper, entity-relationship

I am assigned to create a database in SQL based on an ERD that I studied and recreated a week prior. I am using this app called "Oracle SQL Developer" and trying to learn about creating tables, primary keys, foreign keys, sequences, views, etc. I tested my drafts out on the developer and they keep on coming up with the following errors:
[enter image description here][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vk0cu.png this is some syntax error due to partially recognized rules.

Other errors involve missing right parentheses, tables having more than one primary key, etc. So far, this is my best effort at starting a database:

```
/* CREATE A TABLE FOR CUSTOMER INFORMATION FROM THE GREETING CARD CUSTOMIZATION APPLICATION */
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER
(CUST_EMAIL VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY,
CUST_NAME VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
CUST_PHONE NUMERIC(10) NOT NULL,
CUST_ADDRESS VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
CUST_CITY VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
CUST_STATE VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_CUSTOMER PRIMARY KEY (CUST_EMAIL)
);
/* CREATE A TABLE FOR GREETING CARD AND ENVELOPE ORDER INFORMATION */
CREATE TABLE PRODUCTS
(ORDER_NO NUMERIC(10) PRIMARY KEY,
CUST_EMAIL VARCHAR(10) FOREIGN KEY,
TRACK_ID NUMERIC(10) NOT NULL,
CONF_NO NUMERIC(10) NOT NULL,
ORDER_DATE DATE(10) NOT NULL,
SHIP_DATE DATE(10) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_PRODUCTS PRIMARY KEY (ORDER_NO)
CONSTRAINT FK_PRODUCTS_CUST_EMAIL FOREIGN KEY (CUST_EMAIL) REFERENCES CUSTOMER);
/* CREATE A TABLE FOR PAYMENT INFORMATION */
CREATE TABLE PAYMENT
(PAY_ID NUMERIC(10) PRIMARY KEY,
ORDER_NO NUMERIC(10) FOREIGN KEY,
CARD_TYPE VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
PRICE NUMERIC(10) NOT NULL,
PAY_DATE DATE(10) NOT NULL,
PAY_CONF INTEGER(10) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_PAYMENT PRIMARY KEY (PAY_ID),
CONSTRAINT FK_PAYMENT_ORDER_NO FOREIGN KEY (ORDER_NO) REFERENCES PRODUCTS);
/* CREATE A TABLE FOR PRODUCT DELIVERY INFORMATION */
CREATE TABLE DELIVERY
(DEL_ID NUMERIC(10) PRIMARY KEY,
ORDER_NO NUMERIC(10) FOREIGN KEY,
SHIP_DATE DATE(10) FOREIGN KEY,
DEL_DATE DATE(10) NOT NULL,
STATUS VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
DEL_MODE VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
INVOICE_NO INTEGER(10) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_DELIVERY PRIMARY KEY (DEL_ID),
CONSTRAINT FK_DELIVERY_ORDER_NO FOREIGN KEY (ORDER_NO) REFERENCES PRODUCTS
CONSTRAINT FK_DELIVERY_SHIP_DATE FOREIGN KEY (SHIP_DATE) REFERENCES PRODUCTS);
/* CREATE A TABLE FOR RECIPIENT INFORMATION */
CREATE TABLE RECIPIENT
(STREET_ADDRESS VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY,
NAME VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
CITY VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
STATE VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
ZIP INTEGER(10) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_RECIPIENT PRIMARY KEY (STREET_ADDRESS)
);
```

Where should I place my parentheses if the app is correct in saying that I am missing some of them? Where do I even have more than one primary key and how can I rephrase my lines to reduce them? How can I take my rules from partially recognized to fully recognized?

This is for a college project on relational database systems. I just need to create some tables, primary keys, and foreign keys so I can be allowed to create sequences.

Comment: `FOREIGN KEY` by itself says nothing, you need to add the reference for that foreign key, in a `TABLE (ATTRIBUTE)` way. At least for me, it's easier to search the right sintax for foreign key in internet than creating a so question... https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp

Comment: I think the keys are declared after all the columns. Some sources: [link 1](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/mysql-5.6-en/create-table-foreign-keys.html), [link 2](https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-primary-key/), [link3](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/primary_keys.php).

Comment: Just remove the`FOREIGN KEY` word, you already defined the constraint at the end of your create table script, [Create table foreign key](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/mysql-5.6-en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)

Comment: if you build your ERD in SQL Developer (Data Modeler), it'll generate valid DDL out of the box, for you. Did you know you can create your models/diagrams in SQL Developer?

Comment: how do you fix invalid identifiers and missing parentheses?

Answer (score 2):

- `DATE` and `INTEGER` do not have a precision.
- Either declare the `PRIMARY KEY` inline or out-of-line but you cannot do both.
- Same for foreign keys (and inline foreign keys need the `REFERENCES` keyword and not the `FOREIGN KEY` keywords).
- `VARCHAR` would be better as `VARCHAR2`
- You cannot have a `FOREIGN KEY` that refers to a non-primary key, non-unique column (i.e. `SHIP_DATE`). While you could create a `UNIQUE` composite key on `ORDER_NO` and `SHIP_DATE` and reference that (example below); it is probably better to entirely remove `SHIP_DATE` from the `DELIVERY` table (and then you don't need a foreign key) and just keep it in a single table so the tables are in 3rd normal form. If you want the information to display it then `JOIN` the tables using the `ORDER_NO` foreign key.

```sql
/* CREATE A TABLE FOR CUSTOMER INFORMATION FROM THE GREETING CARD CUSTOMIZATION APPLICATION */
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER(
  CUST_EMAIL   VARCHAR2(10),
  CUST_NAME    VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
  CUST_PHONE   NUMERIC(10) NOT NULL,
  CUST_ADDRESS VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
  CUST_CITY    VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
  CUST_STATE   VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT PK_CUSTOMER PRIMARY KEY (CUST_EMAIL)
);

/* CREATE A TABLE FOR GREETING CARD AND ENVELOPE ORDER INFORMATION */
CREATE TABLE PRODUCTS(
  ORDER_NO   NUMERIC(10),
  CUST_EMAIL VARCHAR2(10),
  TRACK_ID   NUMERIC(10) NOT NULL,
  CONF_NO    NUMERIC(10) NOT NULL,
  ORDER_DATE DATE NOT NULL,
  SHIP_DATE  DATE NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT PK_PRODUCTS PRIMARY KEY (ORDER_NO),
  CONSTRAINT U_PRODUCTS UNIQUE (ORDER_NO, SHIP_DATE),
  CONSTRAINT FK_PRODUCTS_CUST_EMAIL FOREIGN KEY (CUST_EMAIL) REFERENCES CUSTOMER
);

/* CREATE A TABLE FOR PAYMENT INFORMATION */
CREATE TABLE PAYMENT(
  PAY_ID    NUMERIC(10),
  ORDER_NO  NUMERIC(10),
  CARD_TYPE VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
  PRICE     NUMERIC(10) NOT NULL,
  PAY_DATE  DATE NOT NULL,
  PAY_CONF  INTEGER NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT PK_PAYMENT PRIMARY KEY (PAY_ID),
  CONSTRAINT FK_PAYMENT_ORDER_NO FOREIGN KEY (ORDER_NO) REFERENCES PRODUCTS
);

/* CREATE A TABLE FOR PRODUCT DELIVERY INFORMATION */
CREATE TABLE DELIVERY(
  DEL_ID     NUMERIC(10),
  ORDER_NO   NUMERIC(10),
  SHIP_DATE  DATE,                   -- Delete this line
  DEL_DATE   DATE NOT NULL,
  STATUS     VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
  DEL_MODE   VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
  INVOICE_NO INTEGER NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT PK_DELIVERY PRIMARY KEY (DEL_ID),
  CONSTRAINT FK_DELIVERY_ORDER_NO FOREIGN KEY (ORDER_NO) REFERENCES PRODUCTS,
  CONSTRAINT FK_DELIVERY_SHIP_DATE FOREIGN KEY (ORDER_NO, SHIP_DATE) REFERENCES PRODUCTS (ORDER_NO, SHIP_DATE) -- Delete this line.
);

/* CREATE A TABLE FOR RECIPIENT INFORMATION */
CREATE TABLE RECIPIENT(
  STREET_ADDRESS VARCHAR2(10),
  NAME           VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
  CITY           VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
  STATE          VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
  ZIP            INTEGER NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT PK_RECIPIENT PRIMARY KEY (STREET_ADDRESS)
);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=226138ff3d21b18ed16f212b72da0159)*

Comment: thank you for these suggestions. However, I still need help with errors involving the right parentheses missing from the PRODUCTS table and involving a view not existing in the PAYMENT or DELIVERY tables.

Comment: I am also having problem with some invalid identifier in the DELIVERY table, but I don't know what it is.

Comment: @GGomes4 The code in the db<>fiddle works. I'm not sure what you have done differently but you need to work out what you've changed and fix that.